# Finding short and fat paths

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

**Motivation:** In standard augmenting path maxflow algorithms, the inner loop requires finding paths from source to sink in a directed, weighted graph.  Theoretically, it is well-known that in order for the algorithm to even terminate when there are irrational edge capacities, we need to put restrictions on the paths that we find.  The Edmonds-Karp algorithm, for example, tells us to find *shortest* paths.

Empirically, it has been observed that we might also want to find *fat* (is there a better term for this?) paths.  For example, when using *capacity scaling*, we find shortest paths that can bear at least $\epsilon$ amount of flow.  There is no restriction on how long the path can be.  When we can no longer find any paths, we decrease $\epsilon$ and repeat.

I am interested in optimizing the choice of augmenting paths for a very specific application of max-flow, and I want to explore this tradeoff between short and fat paths.  (Note: it is not necessary for me to always solve the problem.  I am most interested in finding the largest lower bound on flow in the shortest amount of wall time.)

> **Question:** Is there a standard way to
>   interpolate between the shortest path
>   approach and the capacity-scaling
>   approach?  That is, is there an
>   algorithm for finding paths that are
>   both short and fat, where ideally some
>   parameter would control how much
>   length in the path we are willing to
>   trade off for fatness?  At the extremes, I'd like to be able to recover
>   shortest paths on one end and capacity scaling-style paths on the other.

Comment: Note that if you try to optimize both shortness and fatness at the same time, you enter the realms of multicriteria optimizsation which means in most cases NP-hardness.

Comment: @dan x: I'm aware of capacity scaling algorithms for max flow, but not the specific one you're describing. Do you have a reference (conference paper, journal article, scribed lecture(s), etc.) describing your version of capacity scaling in detail? I'm curious if there's a known "best way" to initialize and decrement $\epsilon$ (depending on how well-defined this is, it could very naturally lead to a "parameterized" algorithm like you're looking for).

Comment: @Daniel Apon - there is pseudocode for capacity scaling on page 31 of these slides: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg.../07maxflow.pdf

Comment: @Raphael - Note that I'm looking for a single objective that could be e.g. a linear combination of length and fatness. Is that still considered a multicriteria optimization?

Comment: Also, I'm willing to take a "pretty good" path even if it is not optimal.  In capacity scaling, for example, we take any path that is at least as fat as $\epsilon$.  I'd be happy with some analog that takes into account both shortness and fatness.

Comment: dan, if you have a weighted sum (or similar) of some criteria you are left with the basic shortest path problem. Just combine the criteria to a single one and use common algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of your comment about "pretty good but not necessarily optimal," I present the following idea with absolutely no guarantee of optimality!

For completeness, here is the pseudocode that you referred to (Remark: the algorithm linked assumes edge capacities are integers between 1 and C and that flow and residual capacity values are integral):

```
Scaling-Max-Flow(G, s, t, C) {
   foreach e ∈ E f(e) ← 0
   Δ ← smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to C
   G_f ← residual graph

   while (Δ ≥ 1) {
      G_f(Δ) ← Δ-residual graph
      while (there exists augmenting path P in G_f(Δ)) {
         f ← augment(f, C, P)
         update G_f(Δ)
      }
      Δ ← Δ / 2
   }
   return f
}
```

Observe that when $\epsilon$ = 1 ($\epsilon = \Delta$ in the psuedocode), you're just finding paths in shortest to longest order, and when $\epsilon$ is large, you're finding paths in (more or less) fattest to slimmest order. In fact, depending on the instance, the capacity-scaling algorithm finds paths in shortest to longest order within "buckets" of "enough flow."

Then, add another input parameter $0 \le \rho \le 1$ that represents how much you care about "fatness" vs "shortness." In order to ensure we're not massively affecting the runtime, we further require that $\rho$ is a rational number.

Then, each time $\epsilon$ is assigned a value, we additionally take the $\rho$-weighted arithmetic mean (I hope that's the correct term..) between 1 and its current value. That is,

$\epsilon \leftarrow (\rho)\epsilon + (1-\rho)$

For $\rho = 0$, we end up with a pure shortest path algorithm; for $\rho = 1$, we get a pure fattest path algorithm; and for $0 < \rho < 1$ we get something in between. In particular, for some middle value, $\epsilon$ will converge to $\le 1$ more quickly, so you'll get more shortest paths, and fewer fattest paths.

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- it's getting close to what I had in mind.  My one concern is that this is just a different "decay schedule" for capacity scaling, right?

Comment: As you decay more aggressively, you get shorter paths, and as you decay less aggressively you get fatter paths.  What I had in mind was that each path would get a score based on how fat it was and how short it was, then the algorithm would find all paths with score greater than some threshold.

Comment: But if there isn't a standard way of doing this, I can sit down and put some thought into getting an algorithm that does what I want.